# Using querySelector in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to get element with id card1 which was created in createElement() but I cant

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon?limit=12',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  },
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {},
  success: function(result) {
    let data = result;
    data.results.forEach(element => {
      createElement(element); // - here's I create card1
    });
    if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
      let cards = document.querySelector('#card1');
      console.log(cards); // returns null
    };
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

I tried async/await async/defer DOMContentLoaded and readyState - there's the best result
upd. createElement is my function that creates card1:

```
function createElement(elements) {
    console.log(elements);
    $.ajax({
        url: elements.url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
        },
        success: function (result_pokemon) {
           let data_pokemon =  result_pokemon;
        setInnerHtml(data_pokemon.name,data_pokemon.types,data_pokemon.sprites.front_default, data_pokemon.id)
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

And

```
function setInnerHtml(name,types,img, id){
    let innerHtml = `
    <div class="card" id="card${id}" style='width: 18rem;'>
       <div class="card-body">
       <img class="card-img" src="${img}"></img>
       <h5 class="card-title">${name}</h5>`;
       for(let i=0;i<types.length;i++){
        innerHtml +=
       `<p class="card-text ${types[i].type.name}" >${types[i].type.name}</p>`;
       }
       innerHtml +=`
        </div>
        </div>
        `;    
     document.querySelector('.post-list').innerHTML += innerHtml;
}
```

That is all code

Comment: My first guess is `document.readyState` isn't `loading`. Where are you calling this function?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to post the content of your createElement function as well as an example of what data.results looks like.

Comment: Its will work without readyState,but it didnt solve my problem

Comment: Now the question is what is `setInnerHtml()`? Please include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do async/await inside a forEach loop in Javascript. You have to write the loop the old fashioned way. I would try having your createElement return a promise. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon?limit=12',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  },
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {},
  success: async function (result) {
    let data = result;

    let cards = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= data.results.length; i++) {
      let element = data.results[i];
      await createElement(element);
    }

    if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
      let cards = document.querySelector('#card1');
      console.log(cards); // returns null
    };
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("error");
  }
});

function createElement(elements) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: elements.url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      },
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
      },
      success: function (result_pokemon) {
        let data_pokemon = result_pokemon;
        setInnerHtml(data_pokemon.name, data_pokemon.types, data_pokemon.sprites.front_default, data_pokemon.id);
        resolve();
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log("error");
        reject();
      }
    });
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your new elements are not yet in the document. You want to `append` them to a parent element before using `querySelector` to find them.

In your edit I can see that you have another async task to fetch the data for those elements. I'm making the assumption that `setInnerHtml` is the function where the elements are actually added to the DOM.

What you'll need is some way of telling when everything is done. This can be promises, a counter based loader, or even polling.

Here's a quick example of your code using promises and async/await:

```
async function getPokemon() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon?limit=12',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      },
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {},
      success(result) { resolve(result) },
      error(error) { reject(error) }
    });
  });
};

async function fetchDetails(pokemon) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: pokemon.url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      },
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
      },
      success(result) { resolve(result) },
      error(error) { reject(error) }
    });
  });
}

function setInnerHtml(name, types, img, id) {
  let innerHtml = `
  <div class="card" id="card${id}" style='width: 18rem;'>
     <div class="card-body">
     <img class="card-img" src="${img}"></img>
     <h5 class="card-title">${name}</h5>`;
  for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    innerHtml +=
      `<p class="card-text ${types[i].type.name}" >${types[i].type.name}</p>`;
  }
  innerHtml += `
      </div>
      </div>
      `;
  document.querySelector('.post-list').innerHTML += innerHtml;
}

async function main() {
  const pokemon = await getPokemon();
  // Using Promise.all ensures these all run in parallel
  const details = await Promise.all(pokemon.map(fetchDetails))
  // Then we add them all to the document
  details.forEach(data_pokemon => {
    setInnerHtml(
      data_pokemon.name,
      data_pokemon.types,
      data_pokemon.sprites.front_default,
      data_pokemon.id
    );
  });
  // Because setInnerHtml is sync, we can now safely search for cards
  let cards = document.querySelector('#card1');
  console.log(cards); // returns null
}
```

Comment: @IvanKomarnytskiy updated with async/awaitified code

Comment: Thanx but it not creating elements (i dont know why)

Comment: No, absolutely no errors. I tried to console.log pokemon and details in main() but get nothing